# How to count the number of columns with certain elements in it?

Tags: r

I have a matrix

```
    [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10] [,11] [,12] [,13] [,14] [,15] [,16] [,17] [,18] [,19] [,20]
[1,]    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1     1     2     2     2     2     2     2     3     3     3     4
[2,]    2    2    2    2    3    3    3    4    4     5     3     3     3     4     4     5     4     4     5     5
[3,]    3    4    5    6    4    5    6    5    6     6     4     5     6     5     6     6     5     6     6     6
```

I need to count the number of columns with 2 and 3 in it. Eyeballing it, it would be columns 1,11,12,13. That is, 4.

Answer (score 2):

For matrices, this one also works (assume mat is your matrix):

**Old (this will not work if any column has two or more 2s or 3s)**

```
sum(colSums(mat == 2L | mat == 3L) > 1L)
```

**Revised (this one should work)**

```
sum(colSums(mat == 2L) > 0L & colSums(mat == 3L) > 0L)
```

Comment: This won't work if there are more than two `2` or `3` in one column

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. I have revised my answer. @ThomasIsCoding

Answer (score 1):

A base R option

```
sum(sapply(as.data.frame(M),function(v) all(c(2,3)%in%v)))
```

or a method by Allan Cameron

```
sum(apply(M, 2, function(v) all(2:3 %in% v)))
```

where `M` is the matrix

Comment: Or `sum(apply(M, 2, function(v) all(2:3 %in% v)))` to avoid the `as.data.frame`?

Comment: @AllanCameron Yes. I added yours as another option :)